# What is the difference between 'book' and 'books' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

There is a sentence like ' I have book that brags about life.'

I learned that when there is a restricted phrase, we should use 'the' in front of the noun signified.
So, I think that ' I have the book that brags about life.'is right.
What do you think about that?
And what is the difference between 'book' and 'the book' in this sentence in meaning?

Comment: If there is only one book in all the world that brags about life, or if you have previously described a book as bragging about life and are referring to it again, the definite article is correct. If neither of those is the case, the indefinite article may be correct. In every case, though, _book_ **must** take an article. _" I have book that brags about life"_ is always ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

> This is **the** house that Jack built.

Jack built one house. This is the one.

> This is **a** house that Jack built.

Jack built houses. This is one of them.

> This is house that Jack built.<sup>ungrammatical</sup>

With count nouns, an article is required. **house** is a count-noun. With non-count nouns, an article is not required but is admissible. **beer** is a non-count noun:

> This is beer that Jack brewed.<sup>grammatical</sup>

Jack brews beer. This is some of it.

> This is **the** beer that Jack brewed.<sup>grammatical</sup>

Jack has brewed some beer. This is it.